# Why is `max_allowed_packet` shows 2048 even though it's set as 16M in mysqld.cnf

Tags: mysql

I've got the error related to `max_allowed_packet`:

> [S1000] Packet for query is too large (2,127 > 2,048). You can change
>   this value on the server by setting the ‘max_allowed_packet’ variable.

So the limit is 2048. I've checked `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and the value there is 16Mb:

```
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

I've ran the query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Which gave me `2,048`. So the values are different. Is my assumption correct that the value in `mysqld.cnf` specifies limit for server while the query gave me the limit for client side? If so, where do I configure the value for the client side?

By running this query:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

I only set the variable for the current session and as I understand it'll be reset after I restart the database. What's also interesting that:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

still gives me `2,048`m but:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

gives me `16777216`.

I need to set it in the **client configuration file**. But is there such a thing? I've done some reading but it's still vague.

Comment: Do you have another cnf file perhaps that you are reading from? 
Alternatively could someone else have changed it manually using `SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet = 2147483648;`

Comment: *What's also interesting that* If session variable differs from global one - look additional init commands in connection properties.

Comment: @Akina, @IGGt it seems that after I've restarted mysql the values of the session and global variables are the same and the error is now gone, but I can't seem to figure out how running `SET GLOBAL...` helped. Do you maybe have a guess where did the command make the change and why it persisted over database restart?

Comment: In general it is an effect of additional connection init commands on the CLIENT side.

Comment: @Akina, thanks, not sure that's the case here. Anyways, thanks. It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings in my.cnf (etc) are seen only when `mysqld` starts up.

Settings changed by `SET GLOBAL...` are not seen until someone logs in.  But, such settings go away when `mysqld` is restarted.  (This item *probably* explains what you encountered.)

Settings changed for the "session" last only for that one connection, and only until disconnecting.

(MySQL 8.0 has some more situations, due to being about the "persist" changes across restarts.)

(Not all settings have a `GLOBAL/SESSION` split as implied above.)